# Need msbuild file that will publish a Web Application

Tags: msbuild

Has anyone had success making an msbuild file that will publish a Web Application, not the old 2.0 web site but a Web Application?

This is **not** what I am looking for:

<MSBuild Projects="eRx.Web.SecureSiteShell.csproj"   Properties="Configuration=Debug;OutDir=$(OutputFolder)\$(OutputWeb)\bin\;WebProjectOutputDir=$(OutputFolder)\$(OutputWeb)\"   Targets="ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication" />

I tried simply using 'targets:Publish' but I get : Skipping unpublishable project.

Comment: ok no takers huh? I am willing to write an application to do it if anyone knows how. Microsoft gave us this great "Web Application" project so that I can version everything but I can't seem to publish it from anywhere other than the UI. This just doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this just isn't possible. My first hint was getting absolutely no response from this site.

I began to look into making a web setup project but was unsatisfied at having to edit the installation dialogues to get a custom installation folder. All I really need is something that will copy the published output of a Web Application (not Web Site you 2.0 peeps).

I think I have cheated the system by creating a simple Windows Setup program. Surprisingly I am able to include the primary output of my web application which satisfies my need. I DO have to manually add each projects debug symbols if I want them so the process can be lengthly but doable.

Like I said, not completely satisfied because I wanted to get the files in a nice deploy folder for my QA group to work with but feeding them an MSI has its advantages I suppose.

I leave this for anyone to comment on. I still can't believe I can't do this from msBuild or any other tool.

Comment: Found it, http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=711a2eef-b107-4784-9063-c978edc498cd&displaylang=en